# How to extrude a 2D image to 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, shapefile

I have a code that takes the X and Y coordinates of a few buildings from a shapefile and plots them on a 2D graph, like below:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

i = 0
sf = shapefile.Reader('shapefile')

def plotmult():
    global i
    sr = sf.shapeRecords()
    while i < max:
        sr_obj = sr[i]
        sr_points = sr_obj.shape.points
        sr_plot = zip(*sr_points)
        plt.plot(*sr_plot)
        plt.scatter(*sr_plot)
        i = i + 1

max = 500

plotmult()
```

The .dbf file also has a column on the number of stories of each building, and I wanted to be able to multiply this column by a set number in order to find an approximate height for each building, and then extrude the 2D images to 3D, creating a 3D plot.

I've tried using matplotlib but I'm still learning Python so I'm not getting the results I need.

Comment: matplotlib isn't the best tool for 3D plotting -- there are some [gallery examples](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d), of which I'd try the wireframes. If you're doing a lot of 3D plotting, and need to learn a new library anyway, maybe a different library? What are you planning to do a lot of?

Comment: ...actually, I experimented a little and doing it with the wireframes would be pretty annoying.

Comment: There are some really promising answers to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/simple-thematic-mapping-of-shapefile-using-python), for instance.

Comment: Hi @cphlewis. Yes I think I will try using a different library. I've been trying to make it work for a while now with no success. Thanks for the tips, I will look into it :)